# Grunt task Compass fails - Could not find RubyGem compass (>= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gruntjs, npm

I recently transfered machines from an iMac to a new Mac Book Pro with Mavericks. All was well but I noticed that Grunt was crashing when I saved a file (the auto update wasn't working). I tried to update my system but when I run my grunt tasks via the terminal I get the following error:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem compass (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/compass:18
```

Would anyone have any advice on how to fix this? I have removed compass from my project and done an npm install, nothing has changed.

When I run `$ gem list` I get the following:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.5.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4, 1.2.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I then tried running `$ sudo gem update --system` but I got hte following response: `Latest version currently installed. Aborting.`

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I guess a some code requires *compass* gem to use, it could be a code in your **Rakefile**, because I see the `compass:dev` task, it is a rake task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what I had to do. I uninstalled and reinstalled sass and compass then run: `bundle update i18n`

Everything seemed to work after that!

Answer (score 19):

Looks like `SASS` and `Compass` gems are missing, try installing `SASS & Compass`

```
sudo gem install sass

sudo gem install compass
```

For windows use following commands

```
gem install sass

gem install compass
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: thanks for that! sudo gem install sass worked like a charm!