# Why does Sass or Compass not run on tty1 to tty6?

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, tty

When I run `compass watch` on `tty7` using the bash terminal in my Ubuntu 14.04 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) it's all jolly good. However, whenever I try `tty1` to `tty6`, it comes back with the error below:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.6.2, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.5, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:22:in `<main>`
```

If I simply run `sass`, a similar error is observed, but with `sass` in place of `compass`. Thus I think this problem is related to Ruby gems in general.

When I run `whereis sass`, the output is `sass: /usr/local/bin/sass`. I have checked in `tty1` to `tty6` that `/usr/local/bin` is in the `$PATH` variable. I have tried [re-installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21913763/2317532) or just plain [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21017620/2317532) it again but each time the same error is thrown.

The environment is different on `tty1` compared to the terminal, you can see the differences [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/c46w0pty). As you can see, the $PATH variables are the same (albeit in different order), and that `usr/local/bin`, where the gems are installed, are present in both.

**Only when I use [`rvmsudo gem install`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278502/2317532) did it work.** Why does Sass or Compass start in tty7 but not tty1 to tty6? (without me having to install it again)

Comment: Are they sharing the same environment variables or are you running any gemset et. al.? It's most likely not installed.

Comment: @limelights please excuse my stupidity, but I installed it on tty7, it works. I need to install it again on tty1 again? I run `whereis compass` and it says `/usr/local/bin/compass`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278047/could-not-find-rails-0-amongst-gemloaderror, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866380/rvm-sass-compass-issue-with-localhost-sites, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852242/to-specs-could-not-find-chef-0-amongst-gemloaderror

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specifing anything about your running environment / OS / terminal emulator / shell, so it's hard to give any solid diagnostics.

However, it's fairly clear that environment you get in the shell on tty1-6 and the shell you get in a terminal emulator (in X session?) is different.

If I were you, I'd try the following trick:

- run `env >env-tty1` on tty1
- run `env >env-term` in your terminal emulator
- see what's the difference between them, i.e. `diff -u env-tty1 env-term`

Given that you're using RVM, probably the problems are either with `PATH` or some other environment variable missing.

Chances are they're set in some file like `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.profile` - and your bash shell is started slightly differently by `login(1)` on tty1 and by your terminal emulator on tty7. Probably moving everything to `.bash_profile` could help.

Comment: @dayuloli: You've just posted a password for your SMTP server account in public in that file. At the very least, don't forget to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are using `RVM` but it is not loading on tty 1 to 6. Does it work if you load `RVM` after login with:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

(or whatever RVM related lines that are in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files)

Comment: I don't have an `.rvm/` directory in my home directory in any of the terminals.

Comment: But did you originally install/use RVM? Because it is mentioned in your error description.

Comment: @zwippe Thank you for your answer and sorry for the confusion (I'm so confused), I am reinstalling `rvm` now. I deleted it in error when trying suggestion. Guess the best place to start is from nothing!

Comment: Can you explain why even after I deleted the `.rvm/` directory, Compass and Sass still ran fine? When I ran whereis [sass / compass] I get `/usr/local/bin/[sass / compass]`

Comment: That is because bundler installed it there, not RVM. Bundler install gems to `/usr/local` (unless you specified another folder).